# Tabulator and dat.GUI together

Tags: javascript, tabulator, dat.gui

Does anyone know if you can use tabulator and dat.gui together? For lots of operations in tabulator you need to call a method on the table rather than change an object property

ex:

```
tbl =  document.getElementById('tabulator-table');
tbl.toggleColumn('name'); // Hide or show the 'name' column
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Please let me know when you get the chance.

Thank you,

Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dat.gui has 'onChange' and 'onFinishChange' [events](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#7--Events) you can listen for and then call your functions.

```js
function someFunction(value) {
  document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = value;
}

var dummyObject = {someNumber: 1};
var gui = new dat.GUI();
var controller = gui.add(dummyObject, 'someNumber', -5, 5);

// call function on controller change, the current raw value of the control will be sent to the function.
controller.onChange(someFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dataarts/dat.gui/v0.7.6/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<div id="something">1</div>
```